# ng-mouseover/mouseleave animate for each list item

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a list of items with a group of buttons that i want to be displayed when the mouse is hovered over each `li` but as of right now whenever i hover over any `li` , all `item-btn-grp` are display . I want only the `item-btn-grp` for the `li` being hovered over to display. Any help is welcomed thanks in advance. I am using ngAnimate for the animations.

```
.item-btn-grp {
    display:inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 40px;
    border-left: 1px solid #a1a0a0;
    -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1s;
    -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1s;
    -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1s;
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1s;
    right: 0;
}

.item-btn-grp.ng-hide {
  right: -50px;
  opacity:0;
  padding:0 10px;
}


<div id="tasks-list">
    <li class="task-item"  ng-mouseover="myValue = true" ng-mouseleave="myValue = false">
        Do this And then that
        <div class='item-btn-grp' ng-show="myValue" >
            <button class="item-btn-ok"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
            <button class="item-btn-remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="task-item"  ng-mouseover="myValue = true" ng-mouseleave="myValue = false">
        Do this And then that
        <div class='item-btn-grp' ng-show="myValue" >
            <button class="item-btn-ok"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
            <button class="item-btn-remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post working fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Please go through with this link:  [Animations: the Angular Way](https://css-tricks.com/animations-the-angular-way/)

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved directly via css, please use the below css,

```
.task-item:hover .item-btn-grp {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    border-left: 1px solid #a1a0a0;
    -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1s;
    -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1s;
    -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1s;
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1s;
    right: 0;
    opacity:1;
}

.item-btn-grp{
  right: -50px;
  opacity:0;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

Refer this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/NuIgukmNB8e4hBwmt8v0?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a value by item.

Suppose you are using a `ng-repeat`

```
<li class="task-item" ng-repeat="item in taskItems" ng-mouseover="item.myValue = true" ng-mouseleave="item.myValue = false">
    <div class='item-btn-grp' ng-show="item.myValue" >
        <!-- buttons -->
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: but that would mean i have to add a `myValue` to each item just to be able to display buttons on each `li` :/

Comment: I don't know the structure of your items but if they have an id, you could use a map. ng-mouseover="map[item.id] = true", ng-mouseleave="map[item.id] = false", ng-show="map[item.id] === true" and in your controller you initalize it $scope.map = {};